# Free online resources for beginner course

Tags: recursos

Along with [this question](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/944/free-online-resources-for-beginner-course/946#946), what are good, free online resources to learn Spanish?

Important areas such as grammar, vocabulary and pronunciation should be covered.

Comment: This page is obsolete.  Please refer to "Resources for learning Spanish" instead: https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/23617/9385

Answer (score 12):

**Online Websites**

- [BBC Online](http://www.bbc.co.uk/languages/spanish/). (Probably the best so far)
- [Learn spanish](http://www.studyspanish.com/)
- [123 teachme](http://www.123teachme.com/)
- [Destinos: An Introduction to Spanish](http://learner.org/series/destinos/)

**Podcasts**

- [One Minute Spanish](http://itunes.apple.com/us/podcast/one-minute-spanish/id400175575)
- [Coffee Break Spanish](http://itunes.apple.com/podcast/coffee-break-spanish/id201598403)
- [Finally Learn Spanish – Beyond the Basics](http://itunes.apple.com/podcast/spanish-a-finally-learn-spanish/id209618884)
- [InstaLearn Spanish](http://itunes.apple.com/podcast/insta-spanish-lessons/id115018357)
- [Learn Spanish 101](http://itunes.apple.com/podcast/learn-spanish-spanishpod101.com/id270572701)
- [Spanish Survival Guide](http://itunes.apple.com/podcast/learn-spanish-survival-guide/id170271930)
- [Spanish for beginners](http://itunes.apple.com/podcast/spanish-podcasts-for-beginners/id260780223)

More [list of resources](http://www.openculture.com/free_spanish_lessons)

Comment: @LisaBeck - could you transfer the podcasts to the community wiki answer?

Comment: @aparente001 Fedorqui casually suggested I take a look at these and then add any I thought would be good.  I did.  If you don't see any of them on the community wiki, I had a reason for not including it (and this was even before you stressed to me that the list wasn't intended to be a compendium of everything in existence).  I _might_ add more to the community wiki for the podcast section because there is a lot of good stuff out there I'm discovering, but as far as this list goes, I've looked at it, and listened to the selections, and assessed each one of them.

Comment: @LisaBeck - I don't know anything about fedorqui's advice in this regard, so I can't say, for example, maybe you misunderstood, or, for another example, I disagree with his advice.  Since he wasn't active on this page, a ping would not work here. You could open a room to discuss this and invite us both, if you like.  You could bring it up in La Tertulia and ping me there if you like.  But to me, it doesn't make much sense to be improving someone else's answer to a closed question, especially since no one has any way of finding this page....

Comment: ... If the question were open, I would suggest making it a community wiki answer and linking to it from at least one logical place; but the question is closed, and rightly so, I think.  There aren't even any reopen votes that I can see.  Well, for what it's worth, that's my opinion....

Comment: @aparente001 I mentioned this answer in [a comment](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/23617/resources-for-learning-spanish/23635#comment41803_23635) to _Resources for learning Spanish_, since it seemed interesting to at least see if any of these resources would be useful to append in the _Podcasts_ answer.

Comment: @fedorqui - So you're suggesting this page be used as a place to store a draft?  I'm not convinced yet that that's a good idea.

Comment: @aparente001 nop, I am just saying that in this answer here there are some resources that may be interesting, so I encourage people to check them and add them into the _Resources_ page if they are useful.

Comment: So Lisa misunderstood you?  You weren't suggesting that she add to chrisjlee's answer here, but rather, you were suggesting she check out chrisjlee's list, and then post at our main resources page any gems she finds?